# React: useState() onChange: Doesn't log the first letter when I type the first letter in the input field. How can I set state asynchronously?

Tags: html, reactjs, asynchronous, use-state

Let's leave the filteredBookings for now. My problem is that **if I use e.target.value directly instead of assigning it to a state, it works perfectly** (So I dont need this solution). As soon as I set the search term to be a state, then it doesn't take listen to my first click. In case I need to search for 'banana', it will start printing the whole word after 'a' and not after 'b'. And the first log in the console is not undefined, but just empty.

The reason is probably because the setting has to be done asynchroniously. But how? :/

```
  const [searchWord, setSearchWord] = useState("");
  const [filteredBookings, setfilteredBookings] = useState([]);

  const handleFilteredItems = ({ target }) => {
    setSearchWord(target.value);
    console.log(searchWord);
    
    const filteredBookings = bookings.filter((booking) => {
      return booking.customerFirstName
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchWord.toLowerCase());
    });
    
    // setfilteredBookings(filteredBookings);
  };
```

First and second lines in the console:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The state will be set at the end of the current function. So your `includes` is still using the previous state. You could do like this rather:

```
const handleFilteredItems = ({ target }) => {
    const { value } = target
    setSearchWord(value);
    
    const filteredBookings = bookings.filter((booking) => {
       return booking.customerFirstName
         .toLowerCase()
         .includes(value.toLowerCase());
    });
    setfilteredBookings(filteredBookings);
};
```

***EDIT Based on your comments.***

I think the problem is the way you approach the hook. You should get the filteredBookings outside of the handleFilteredItems, as such:

```
const handleFilteredItems = ({ target }) => {
    const { value } = target
    setSearchWord(value);
};

const filteredBookings = bookings.filter((booking) => {
    return booking.customerFirstName
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(searchWord.toLowerCase());
});
```

and remove this line:

```
  const [filteredBookings, setfilteredBookings] = useState([]);
```

This will update the filteredBookings value at every state change.

Comment: Doesn't work, I think you are doing the same thing. The key is to make it asynchronous. What you're doing is just a destructuring of the target.value to value. And then ofc you use value.toLowerCase() there but this is also somethign that doesn't work.

Comment: I am not doing the same thing, I am using the new value for the filtering while you were using the previous value. But maybe we need to have a bigger picture of the issue/component to solve it. Where is the handleFilteredItems called ? what is the problem you want to solve exactly ?

Comment: The function is just called on an input field.         onChange={handleFilteredItems}

Comment: change you console log to value as well if the console log is the problem. console.log(value)

Comment: So as I said above, I don't want a solution that takes e.target.value directly, but instead I need to set it to a state. In your function you are setting the searchword, but never use it!

Comment: also what's the shape of your bookings objects ?

Comment: why do you need to set a state if you never use it ? I guessed you needed the state as you used in somewhere else (in your input field value to be updated). What is the problem in using the e.target.value as it's the right one anyway ?

Comment: setState is an async function you should await it before using it's value

Comment: but there is not added value in awaiting compare to using the e.target.value directly. Doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: Don't think about this specific case. Let's say that I would need the state. Then how can I make it asynchronous? Above I said that: "if I use e.target.value directly instead of assigning it to a state, it works perfectly.", so I know that your approach works from the beginning. So the way I am posting is to learn t he asynchronous way of doing that :D

Comment: you should not really need async in your useState hooks. But here is for example a custom useState hook using promise to be awaited:
https://ysfaran.github.io/blog/post/0002-use-state-with-promise/
I think the problem is more how you want to use your hooks. Your filtering should be directly inside your rendering, using the state as a filtering value and that would be rerender each time you change state. Meaning you don't need a state for your filteredBookings you can just render them or assign them to a constant but outside of handleFilteredItems. want me to update the answer with this ?

Comment: Sure, I guess it would be also nice for the future readers to have a complete answer of the problem. But now it makes sense. I see your point!

Comment: check my edit please, hope it's clear enough

Comment: Now we removed the filteredBookings state :P

Comment: So I guess there's no solution to keep them both

Comment: Well my first solution, but what's the point. Whether you use a state or a const the value will be the same. Are you setting the state of filteredBookings somwhere else ?